# Organize array based on hierarchy of parent field

Tags: php

I have a table for 'Categories' on the application I am building with PHP. Each category can have a children category and so on. For example:

```
-Computer
--Laptops
---Apple
---Dell
--Monitor
---LCD
---Ultrawide
```

I need to organize an array hierarchically like the example above. Considering that on my Table I only save 3 fields:

```
id
name_cateogry
parent_id
```

So I save only the first direct parent_id. If it is the first level, parent_id is null. For all other levels, parent_id receives the id of the parent level. 
I am having a hard time creating a script that organizes the array hierarchically, considering many levels. 
I would like a suggestion of how to accomplish that with PHP, so I can show the categories hierarchically on the application.

Comment: what about the categories that doen't belong in any other categories i.e; Computer ?

Comment: In this case, the column on the database is null.

Comment: Fetch all, iterate result and build a new array from it until you have the structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will help you, you can make an tree from your data. 
So first you need to fetch all the data and then use this `makeTree function` to make a tree for it

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [    
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "hi",
        "parent_id" => null,
    ],
    [    
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "hi2",
        "parent_id" => 1,
    ],
    [    
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "hi3",
        "parent_id" => 2,
    ],
    [    
        "id" => 4,
        "name" => "h4",
        "parent_id" => 1,
    ],
    [    
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "hi5",
        "parent_id" => null,
    ],
];

function makeTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = makeTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

$tree = makeTree($array);
print_r( $tree );
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => hi
            [parent_id] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => hi2
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => hi3
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => h4
                            [parent_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => hi5
            [parent_id] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This script does exactly what I needed. It organized the array hierarchically as I needed. Fantastic. Thanks for your time spent helping others.